# Roll your own Multiplayer iPhone setup?

Tags: iphone

I've been looking into the various options for implementing multiplayer (internet) in iPhone games. Game Center, OpenFeint etc are obviously very good, stable and feature-rich. But I can't help thinking my needs are a lot simpler than what they provide.

If I wanted to put together a simple 2d tank game, could I not just..

- setup a mysql server on the web, with some get/set php scripts to actas 'web services'.
- when you open the game, a call is made to the server, to log that you're 'available'.
- when you select Play, a call is made to retrieve a list of 'available' IP's.
- you select an opponent, remote IP is stored locally.
- game starts, UDP handles the data between your IP and your opponent's IP.

..or would that never work? apologies, I'm very much a n00b at gaming/networking dev!

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the [complexities that dtuckernet points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8836824/2998), there are few other things to consider:

- You need to think about the cost of running and supporting the web server. Can you maintain the same or better uptime than Apple and OpenFeint?
- GameCentre promotes games that support it. The App Store adds an icon, and Game Centre itself lists games that your friends own. Don't underestimate the effect of free advertising!
- Even if the code it easy (which I suspect isn't true), why take the risk of developing your own when there is well-tested code available for free?

Incidentally, depending on your requirements, you may want to use a hybrid approach. For example, Game Centre has a maximum of four players per game when Apple hosts it. You can find players using GC and then run the games itself on your own server.

Comment: Plus you would do well to make it as efficient as Game Center. Game Center, although it may seem complicated (many classes and delegates) it does work vey well, and you have lots of documentation. Incidentally, I'm working
on adding Game Center to a 2D tank game (I'll be impressed if anyone - excluding people I know - can guess it!), and Game Center works well.

Comment: @Stephen - thanks for the answer, the web server would just be used for matching, I'd imagine most commercial hosts could offer suitable uptime? Yes the GC promotion is a bonus, I hadn't thought of that. Yeah you're probably right, my instinct though would be to at least attempt to write my own lean solution if possible, as a learning exercise if nothing else. I'd use GC as a fallback once I realised how much effort is involved though! :o)

Answer (score 0):

That would certainly work, but implementing this can be a bit harder than it seems initially.  You have to handle things like NAT/Firewall traversal and if you are using UDP you need to implement some type of a heartbeat to ensure you know when devices have disconnected (and handle it accordingly).

In most all cases, you would be better off working with a solution that already has these problems solved.